# Mustache.js should be able to handle/display empty string

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

```
 {{#Version}} Product Version={{{Version}}}{{Version}}
```

I am completely new to mustache.js, apologies if the question is not clear.

In the above line i am able to get Product Version if the version is not empty but i also wanted to be able to get Product Version even when Version is empty.

Mustache will drop 'Product Version' from the output if Version is empty.

```
Product Version =''
```

Comment: Can you provide an accurate representation of the object you are rendering? I suspect whatever "Product Version" is has a length of zero when it is empty.

Answer (score 4):

This way you can handle empty values so you still get `ProductVersion`:

```
Product Version={{#Version}}{{{Version}}}{{/Version}}{{^Version}}''{{/Version}}
```

Where `{{^Version}}{{/Version}}` is called an inverted section and will be rendered if the value of that section's tag is null, undefined, false, falsy or an empty list. As it is explained in the [doc](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#inverted-sections).

Answer (score 2):

You can show the version if it is not empty and show anything otherwise:

`{{#Version}}<b>{{Version}}</b>{{/Version}} {{^Version}}Anything{{/Version}}`